# Magento checkout page phone number mask

Tags: magento2, checkout, input-mask

I need to implement international number mask in magento 2.1 checkout page
phone number field like the below image [image]

so I am requesting that any one know how to implement this code in magento 2.1 checkout page

Git hub URL for this script https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: not yet @PushpendraSingh

Answer (score 0):

I found exact requirement with below Magento module https://github.com/MaxMage/international-telephone-input
so it will be definitely useful for such cases